# Excel Fully Qualifying Range (Cells(),Cells())

Tags: vba, excel

I know many people have talked about fully qualifying ranges. I just want to know how deep you need to go with it to avoid problems.

In the example, I have qualified my worksheet using a dimensioned variable. Is it then necessary to be 100% reliable, to further qualify within the range parentheses?

```
dim myWS as Worksheet
set myWS = Thisworkbook.Activesheet
```

-- Use method A?

```
myWS.Range(Cells(1,5), Cells(500,20)).ClearContents
```

-- Or method B?

```
myWS.Range(myWS.Cells(1,5), myWS.Cells(500,20)).ClearContents
```

Does "Cells" inside Range parentheses default to reference myWS.Range in which it was called or does "Cells" default to reference the active sheet?

If myWS were set to a sheet other than the active sheet, would I get unexpected results from Cells?

It's not hard, except I will have to go back and change it in many places if you say that the second way is more trustworthy!

Comment: The `Cells` objects reference the active sheet. If `myWS` is not active when this line gets executed, VBA will throw an error.

Comment: I am not sure but you can easily test it, myWS.range(myAnotherWS.cell, someOtherWs.cell)

Comment: `Method B` is the right way

Comment: Search Stackoverflow. I have already answered similar question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962890/2-ways-for-clearcontents-on-vba-excel-but-1-work-fine-why

Comment: Thanks @SiddharthRout Rout. I had searched, but somehow missed exactly the answer I was looking for. Solved, done, now to the work of finding all of these mistakes in my 10000 LOC.

Answer (score 3):

Method A will only work if your myWS is active at the time of being called. Method B is more robust, as are method C:

```
myWS.Range(Cells(1,5).Address, Cells(500,20).Address).ClearContents
```

or method D:

```
myWS.Range("E1:T500")
```

Comment: Hmm.. C is interesting. I will experiment with it. D is no good for me because I would always have variable row/column. The example was an oversimplification.  Looks like B is probably the way to go.