# What is the default scope of worksheets and cells and range?

Tags: excel, vba

When you just type worksheets() what is the default scope ActiveWorkbook or ThisWorkbook? For those who do not know these distinctions they are extremely important especially in Excel 2013 when you want macros to run when you switch to different workbooks.

Comment: It is Activeworkbook unless otherwise specify in preceding codes

Comment: @Alex is there a way to change the default behavior with preceding code so that it always references ThisWorkbook? Or would I have to simply declare ThisWorkbook for each time I grab something (this is how I do it currently) .

Comment: As Tim's answer below, you could put your code in thisworkbook module and unqualified worksheets will be default to thisworkbook

Comment: @Alex what is an unqualified worksheet vs a qualified worksheet?

Comment: sorry it was poorly explained.  I meant to say an unqualified worksheet() object.

Comment: @Alex Just making sure there was no secret way to change this default behavior in certain objects. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if there are tricky ways, say for e.g. changing registry for the allocated object properities (this goes beyond normal vba coding).  Other than that it is pretty much straight forward as Tim's answer mentioned.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In a standard module an unqualified `Worksheets()` will always reference the ActiveWorkbook. In the `ThisWorkbook` module, the implicit qualifier is `Me` and that will reference the containing workbook.

Likewise, an unqualified `Range()` or `Cells()` (or `Rows()`/`Columns()`) in a standard module will reference the ActiveSheet, but in a sheet code module the implicit qualifier is `Me`, and will reference the corresponding worksheet.

```
Unqualified...    |   Where            | Implicit Qualifier
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Worksheets(),     |  ThisWorkbook      | Containing workbook (Me)
Sheets()          |  --------------------------------------------------
                  |  Any other module  | Active workbook (via [_Global])
-----------------------------------------------------------------------                     
Range(), Cells(), |  Sheet module      | Containing sheet (Me)
Rows(), Columns(),|  --------------------------------------------------
Names()           |  Any other module  | Active sheet (via [_Global])
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The easy way to avoid having to remember *any* of this is to *always fully qualify* any `Worksheets`, `Sheets`, `Range`, `Cells`, or `Names` reference.

Qualify the member call with `Me` when referring to `ThisWorkbook` in that module's code-behind, or when referring to `Sheet1` in that module's code-behind.