# Range error setting range in VBA using Range(Cells,Cells)

Tags: vba, excel

I am reworking the code in an older worksheet to update it and make it more efficient.

I have a subroutine that formats a data table but I am getting an error where I dont see why I am getting one. My VBA is a bit rusty but the following code should be working

```
Sub FormatPnLDataTable(tableRange As Range)
    Dim tempRange As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim lStartRow As Long, lEndRow As Long, lLastCol As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("PandLDataTable")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    lStartRow = tableRange.Row
    lEndRow = lStartRow + tableRange.Rows.Count
    lLastCol = tableRange.Columns.Count

    'format the whole table with border
    With tableRange
        'format borders
        'code removed for brevity
    End With
    'set range for the top row of table
    Set tempRange = ws.Range(Cells(lStartRow, 1), Cells(lStartRow, lLastCol))
```

The code is erring on this line

```
 Set tempRange = ws.Range(Cells(lStartRow, 1), Cells(lStartRow, lLastCol))
```

but the worksheet (ws) is valid, and the variables all have their proper values
for this particular instance, lStartRow is 1, lEndRow is 15 and lLastCol is 35

Comment: Try fully qualifying the `.Cells` property, and see if that helps. It would look like: `Set tempRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(lStartRow, 1), ws.Cells(lStartRow, lLastCol))`

Comment: True, if the active sheet is different than ws it would error out

Comment: See also: [Is the . in .Range necessary when defined by .Cells?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368220/is-the-in-range-necessary-when-defined-by-cells).

Comment: adding . to the Cells call is not appropriate here, and thus errs

Comment: The marked as duplicate is not even relevant as im not counting rows, which is already done correctly

Comment: The marked as duplicate is **exactly** the same identical problem. Read the post. This has been asked hundreds of times already.

Comment: @Matt's Mug so when searching SO for this problem before I posted, I should have also looked for posts titled "Counting rows in another sheet"?..hardly

Comment: @dinotom - "marked as duplicate" is not a criticism of you personally and you shouldn't see it as such.  It's just part of the process here to try to reduce the amount of duplication between posts.

Comment: @Tim Williams...I'm fully aware of that but trying to intimate that finding the post he is referring to with the problem I was having is absurd, I'd never find that post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Set tempRange = ws.Range(Cells(lStartRow, 1), Cells(lStartRow, lLastCol))
```

Here although you've used `ws` to qualify the `Range` call, it does *not* automatically apply to the `Cells` calls - in a regular module these will by default refer to the ActiveSheet.

This will be more robust:

```
Set tempRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(lStartRow, 1), ws.Cells(lStartRow, lLastCol))
```

See also: [What is the default scope of worksheets and cells and range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439376/what-is-the-default-scope-of-worksheets-and-cells-and-range)

Comment: Yes, I normally wrap all the code for a sheet within a With statement and use .Cells, should've stuck with that format here as well.