# Run-Time Error '1004' on VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a Run-Time error '1004' (Application-defined or object-defined error). It's happening on the second to last line of code.

Also, does anyone know how to define the answer I get on the same line of code?

```
Private Sub selectTable()

Dim startingRow As Integer
Dim endingRow As Integer
Dim startingColumn As Integer
Dim endingColumn As Integer
Dim selectRow As Integer
Dim selectColumn As Integer

startingRow = 13 'This is the row where the table you are sihing to select starts
startingColumn = 5 'This is the row where the table you are wishing to select starts

endingRow = 0 'Variable to hold count of how many rows of data there are
endingColumn = 0 'Variable to hold count of how many columns of data there are

While Cells(startingRow, startingColumn) <> "" 'Counts number of rows that have data
    endingRow = endingRow + 1
    startingRow = startingRow + 1
    Wend

startingRow = 13 'This is the row where the table you are sihing to select starts
startingColumn = 5 'This is the row where the table you are wishing to select starts

While Cells(startingRow, startingColumn) <> "" 'Counts number of columns that have data
    endingColumn = endingColumn + 1
    startingColumn = startingColumn + 1
    Wend

startingRow = 13 'This is the row where the table you are sihing to select starts
startingColumn = 5 'This is the row where the table you are wishing to select starts

selectRow = startingRow + endingRow - 1
selectColumn = startingColumn + endingColumn - 1

Worksheets("General Information").Range(Cells(Row1, Col1), Cells(Row3, Col3)).Select 'Selects the entire range of the desired table

End Sub
```

Comment: are Row1, Row3, Col1 and Col3 defined anywhere?  I don't see them in the code you posted.

Comment: I'm an idiot haha I changed all the variables and didn't realize I needed to update those. Thank you!

Comment: Google "VBA Option Explicit" to help with things like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
With Worksheets("General Information")
    .Range(.Cells(Row1, Col1), .Cells(Row3, Col3)).Select
End with
```

See: [What is the default scope of worksheets and cells and range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439376/what-is-the-default-scope-of-worksheets-and-cells-and-range/28439984#28439984)