# Excel, VBA, .ClearContents with referenced range, error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use .clearcontents on range that is referenced by with some .offset, and I'm having trouble

I know that this works

```
Sub clear1_1()

Workbooks("xyz").Sheets("abc").range("A2:A3").ClearContents

End Sub
```

but if I try this it does not

```
Sub clear2()

Dim region As range
Set region = range("S509:AD618")
Workbooks("xyz").Worksheets("abc").range(region).ClearContents

end sub
```

I do understand from other postings, that it has something to do with object defyining, but I have no idea where I do mistake, what I need to write.

Final macro is run from one workbook, and is supposed to .clearcontents in other not activated workbook.

My code looks like this

```
sub Macro()

..... ton of code
Dim filename as string
dim sheetname as string
dim address3, address4 as string

filename = "xyz"
sheetname = "abc"  ' both variables that are loaded in other part

address3 and address4 loaded in other part


'here is where i get the error
sheets(sheetname).Range(Range(address3).Offset(0, 12).Address & ":" & Range(address4).Offset(-1, 23)).ClearContents


end sub
```

I can probably bypass it with .value=""
But I'm looking to learn. Thank you for any response in advance.

EDIT 1
Hi Scott, doesn't make it. Posting bigger part of my code

```
If mapanchorsuccess = True And map1success = True And map2success = True Then
    If Workbooks(Filename).Sheets(startws).Range(address1).Offset(10, 13).HasFormula = True Then
                With Workbooks(wbm).Sheets("Report") 'report
                    .Range("A" & reportrow).Value = runnumber
                    .Range("B" & reportrow).Value = Filename
                    .Range("C" & reportrow).Value = Workbooks(Filename).Sheets(startws).Name
                    .Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=.Range("D" & reportrow), Address:=FilePath & Filename, SubAddress:=Workbooks(Filename).Sheets(startws).Name & "!A1"
                    .Range("E" & reportrow).Value = "Error"
                    .Range("F" & reportrow).Value = "rolling probably done already in this sheet"
                    reportrow = reportrow + 1
                End With

    Else
        With Workbooks(Filename).Sheets(startws)
            .Range(Range(address1).Offset(0, 12).Address & ":" & Range(address2).Offset(0, 14).Address).Copy _
            Range(Range(address1).Address & ":" & Range(address2).Offset(0, 2).Address)
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

            .Range(Range(address1).Offset(0, 16).Address & ":" & Range(address2).Offset(0, 16).Address).Copy _
            Range(Range(address1).Offset(0, 3).Address & ":" & Range(address2).Offset(0, 23).Address)
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                    With Workbooks(wbm).Sheets("Report") 'report
                        .Range("A" & reportrow).Value = runnumber
                        .Range("B" & reportrow).Value = Filename
                        .Range("C" & reportrow).Value = Workbooks(Filename).Sheets(startws).Name
                        .Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=.Range("D" & reportrow), Address:=FilePath & Filename, SubAddress:=Workbooks(Filename).Sheets(startws).Name & "!A1"
                        .Range("E" & reportrow).Value = "Completed"
                        .Range("F" & reportrow).Value = "region1 rolled forward"
                        reportrow = reportrow + 1
                    End With


            .Range(Range(address3).Offset(0, 12).Address & ":" & Range(address4).Offset(-1, 23).Address).Copy _
            Range(Range(address3).Address & ":" & Range(address4).Offset(-1, 11).Address)

            '///// here the error 1004 occurs
            .Range(Range(address3).Offset(0, 12).Address & ":" & Range(address4).Offset(-1, 23).address).clearcontent
        End With
    End If
End If
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439376/what-is-the-default-scope-of-worksheets-and-cells-and-range/28439984#28439984

Comment: It would have worked if you followed what I put.  You need to put the `.` in front of each Range inside the `()` Use this which is exactly like the one I provided below `.Range(.Range(address3).Offset(0, 12), .Range(address4).Offset(-1, 23)).clearcontent`

Comment: It was missing an `s` on the end `.Range(.Range(address3).Offset(0, 12), .Range(address4).Offset(-1, 23)).clearcontents`

Comment: Getting error 438 for a change. `'///// here the error 1004 occurs
                                                                                            .Range(.Range(address3).Offset(0, 12).Address & ":" & .Range(address4).Offset(-1, 23).Address).clearcontent
End With`

Comment: See my last comment. you are missing the `s` on the end.

Comment: It seems it works correctly now. Thousend times thank you. The way I understand it , is that each .Range(address....  when compounding the range, says to excel specifically which workbook.sheet.cell use in compounding. Correct? Again thank you for your time and patience

Comment: See @TimWilliams link, he explains it better than I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workbook and sheet need to be set with the variable.

Then when using it since it is a range itself just refer to it.

```
Sub clear2()

Dim region As range
Set region = Workbooks("xyz").Worksheets("abc")range("S509:AD618")
region.ClearContents

end sub
```

As to your next code; that is a different problem.  The ranges inside the `()` need to allocated to the correct sheet parentage or it will use the active sheet.

The easiest is with a `With` block:

```
With sheets(sheetname)
    .Range(.Range(address3).Offset(0, 12), .Range(address4).Offset(-1, 23)).ClearContents
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, but it turned out to be very simple. I had a row of cells merged together between columns `E` and `F`, so when I used this command I had to set the `ClearContents` from the top corner of my `E` column to the bottom row of my `F` column.

What did **not** work:

```
Range("E1:E10").Clear Contents
```

What **did** work:

```
Range("E1:F10").ClearContents
```

I can't believe such a simple thing left me so thwarted.