# Excel Custom Function not recalculating in multiple Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm going to apologize right now if this question is not formatted correctly as I'm new to this site.

A colleague wrote all the code and started the array to which I finished (the array) to create the UDF below to reduce the number of formulas that I was using before to find the material density of different metals and modify the formula as needed depending on the shape of the part in order to calculate the weight.

The problem I'm having is this UDF is used in multiple worksheets (45 sheets) within one workbook which all the worksheets total up to a summary tab.  In order to get all the worksheet formula's to calculate properly I either have to double click on each individual cell to force it to recalculate or I highlight all the cells and go to Data>Text to Columns> and click Finish to force all the highlighted cells to recalculate.

I have tried to use shortcuts (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to force the UDF to recalculate) as well as Application.Volatile at the beginning of the code however they only recalculate one worksheet and not all of them.  The sheets that it doesn't recalculate it shows `#value!` in the cell.

As I'm not the only one who uses this document this creates a headache for myself.

Here's the code.  The colleague who wrote it put in some text to help me with troubleshooting it in the future.

```
' We want our function to do the following:
' 1)  Create new function called "MATWEIGHT" and the output I want is a Double (a decimal number)  
' 2)  The inputs I want to bring into the function are "size" and "matl" which are a double and a string respectively.

Public Function MatType(matl As String) As Double

    'Dim outputWeight As Double      'This is a variable declaration - it's good to assign our output to a temporary variable
    'outputWeight = size * 2         'Take the size and multiply by 2
    'MATWEIGHT = outputWeight & matl       'Set the function name to our output to give us our answer

    Dim MatType1(98, 1) As String
    Dim flag As Integer
    flag = 0
    Dim matlDes As String
    matlDes = ""

    MatType1(0, 0) = "304SS - ANGLE"
    MatType1(1, 0) = "304SS - CHANNEL"
    MatType1(2, 0) = "304SS - FLAT BAR"
    MatType1(3, 0) = "304SS - HSS"
    MatType1(4, 0) = "304SS - I-BEAM"
    MatType1(5, 0) = "304SS - PIPE"
    MatType1(6, 0) = "304SS - PLATE"
    MatType1(7, 0) = "304SS - ROUND BAR"
    MatType1(8, 0) = "304SS - SQUARE BAR"
    MatType1(9, 0) = "304SS - WF BEAM"
    MatType1(10, 0) = "410SS - FLAT BAR"
    MatType1(11, 0) = "410SS - PLATE"
    MatType1(12, 0) = "410SS - ROUND BAR"
    MatType1(13, 0) = "420SS - FLAT BAR"
    MatType1(14, 0) = "420SS - PLATE"
    MatType1(15, 0) = "420SS - ROUND BAR"
    MatType1(16, 0) = "44W - PLATE"
    MatType1(17, 0) = "44W CAT 1 - PLATE"
    MatType1(18, 0) = "50W - ANGLE"
    MatType1(19, 0) = "50W - BAR GRATING"
    MatType1(20, 0) = "50W - CHANNEL"
    MatType1(21, 0) = "50W - MC CHANNEL"
    MatType1(22, 0) = "50W - FLAT BAR"
    MatType1(23, 0) = "50W - HSS"
    MatType1(24, 0) = "50W - I-BEAM < 8in"
    MatType1(25, 0) = "50W - I-BEAM > 10in"
    MatType1(26, 0) = "50W - PIPE"
    MatType1(27, 0) = "50W - PLATE"
    MatType1(28, 0) = "50W - ROUND BAR"
    MatType1(29, 0) = "50W - SQUARE BAR"
    MatType1(30, 0) = "50W - WF BEAM"
    MatType1(31, 0) = "50W CAT 3 - PLATE"
    MatType1(32, 0) = "630SS - FLAT BAR"
    MatType1(33, 0) = "630SS - PLATE"
    MatType1(34, 0) = "630SS - ROUND BAR"
    MatType1(35, 0) = "700QT - PLATE"
    MatType1(36, 0) = "ALUMINUM - ANGLE"
    MatType1(37, 0) = "ALUMINUM - CHANNEL"
    MatType1(38, 0) = "ALUMINUM - FLAT BAR"
    MatType1(39, 0) = "ALUMINUM - HSS"
    MatType1(40, 0) = "ALUMINUM - I-BEAM"
    MatType1(41, 0) = "ALUMINUM - PIPE"
    MatType1(42, 0) = "ALUMINUM - PLATE"
    MatType1(43, 0) = "ALUMINUM - ROUND BAR"
    MatType1(44, 0) = "ALUMINUM - SQUARE BAR"
    MatType1(45, 0) = "ALUMINUM - WF BEAM"
    MatType1(46, 0) = "BRASS - PIPE"
    MatType1(47, 0) = "BRASS - PLATE"
    MatType1(48, 0) = "BRASS - ROUND BAR"
    MatType1(49, 0) = "BRONZE - PIPE"
    MatType1(50, 0) = "BRONZE - PLATE"
    MatType1(51, 0) = "BRONZE - ROUND BAR"
    MatType1(52, 0) = "NYLATRON - PLATE"
    MatType1(53, 0) = "NYLATRON - ROUND BAR"
    MatType1(54, 0) = "UHMW - PLATE"
    MatType1(55, 0) = "UHMW - ROUND BAR"
    MatType1(56, 0) = "ANCHORS"
    MatType1(57, 0) = "BUSHINGS"
    MatType1(58, 0) = "ROLLER - AXLE"
    MatType1(59, 0) = "ROLLER - BEARING"
    MatType1(60, 0) = "ROLLER - SEALS"
    MatType1(61, 0) = "ROLLER - WHEEL"
    MatType1(62, 0) = "ROLLER ASS'Y, 210 DIA."
    MatType1(63, 0) = "ROLLER ASS'Y, 270 DIA."
    MatType1(64, 0) = "ROLLER ASS'Y, 380 DIA."
    MatType1(65, 0) = "ROLLER ASS'Y, 440 DIA."
    MatType1(66, 0) = "ROLLER ASS'Y, 660 DIA."
    MatType1(67, 0) = "ROLLER ASS'Y, 228 DIA."
    MatType1(68, 0) = "ROLLER ASS'Y, 250 DIA."
    MatType1(69, 0) = "ROLLER ASS'Y, 381 DIA."
    MatType1(70, 0) = "ROLLER ASS'Y, 457 DIA."
    MatType1(71, 0) = "ROLLER ASS'Y, 530 DIA."
    MatType1(72, 0) = "GUIDE WHEEL ASSEMBLIES"
    MatType1(73, 0) = "GUIDE WHEEL ASSEMBLIES W/ SPRINGS"
    MatType1(74, 0) = "HARDWARE"
    MatType1(75, 0) = "HEATERS, GAIN"
    MatType1(76, 0) = "MACHINING INSERTS"
    MatType1(77, 0) = "MISC"
    MatType1(78, 0) = "NAME PLATES"
    MatType1(79, 0) = "PAINT - CHEAP"
    MatType1(80, 0) = "PAINT - MIDDLE"
    MatType1(81, 0) = "PAINT - EXPENSIVE"
    MatType1(82, 0) = "RIGGING, SHACKLES"
    MatType1(83, 0) = "RIGGING, WIRE ROPE SLINGS"
    MatType1(84, 0) = "RUBBER"
    MatType1(85, 0) = "SEALS - FRAME"
    MatType1(86, 0) = "SEALS - BULB"
    MatType1(87, 0) = "SEALS - BOTTOM"
    MatType1(88, 0) = "SEALS - WIND"
    MatType1(89, 0) = "SHEAVE BUSHING"
    MatType1(90, 0) = "SHEAVE PIN"
    MatType1(91, 0) = "SHEAVES"
    MatType1(92, 0) = "SPRINGS"
    MatType1(93, 0) = "STAIR TREADS"
    MatType1(94, 0) = "TBD"
    MatType1(95, 0) = "WELDING WIRE - MILD STEEL"
    MatType1(96, 0) = "WELDING WIRE - STAINLESS"
    MatType1(97, 0) = "WOOD"
    MatType1(98, 0) = "GUIDE ROLLER - WHEEL"
    MatType1(0, 1) = "Structural"
    MatType1(1, 1) = "Structural"
    MatType1(2, 1) = "Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(3, 1) = "Structural"
    MatType1(4, 1) = "Structural"
    MatType1(5, 1) = "Structural"
    MatType1(6, 1) = "Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(7, 1) = "Round Bar"
    MatType1(8, 1) = "Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(9, 1) = "Structural"
    MatType1(10, 1) = "Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(11, 1) = "Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(12, 1) = "Round Bar"
    MatType1(13, 1) = "Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(14, 1) = "Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(15, 1) = "Round Bar"
    MatType1(16, 1) = "Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(17, 1) = "Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(18, 1) = "Structural"
    MatType1(19, 1) = "Bar Grating"
    MatType1(20, 1) = "Structural"
    MatType1(21, 1) = "Structural" = mat
    MatType1(22, 1) = "Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(23, 1) = "Structural"
    MatType1(24, 1) = "Structural"
    MatType1(25, 1) = "Structural"
    MatType1(26, 1) = "Structural"
    MatType1(27, 1) = "Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(28, 1) = "Round Bar"
    MatType1(29, 1) = "Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(30, 1) = "Structural"
    MatType1(31, 1) = "Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(32, 1) = "Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(33, 1) = "Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(34, 1) = "Round Bar"
    MatType1(35, 1) = "Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(36, 1) = "Structural"
    MatType1(37, 1) = "Structural"
    MatType1(38, 1) = "Aluminum Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(39, 1) = "Structural"
    MatType1(40, 1) = "Structural"
    MatType1(41, 1) = "Structural"
    MatType1(42, 1) = "Aluminum Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(43, 1) = "Aluminum Round Bar"
    MatType1(44, 1) = "Aluminum Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(45, 1) = "Structural"
    MatType1(46, 1) = "Brass Round Bar"
    MatType1(47, 1) = "Brass Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(48, 1) = "Brass Round Bar"
    MatType1(49, 1) = "Brass Round Bar"
    MatType1(50, 1) = "Brass Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(51, 1) = "Brass Round Bar"
    MatType1(52, 1) = "UHMW Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(53, 1) = "UHMW Round Bar"
    MatType1(54, 1) = "UHMW Plate / Flat Bar"
    MatType1(55, 1) = "UHMW Round Bar"
    MatType1(56, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(57, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(58, 1) = "Round Bar"
    MatType1(59, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(60, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(61, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(62, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(63, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(64, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(65, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(66, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(67, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(68, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(69, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(70, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(71, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(72, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(73, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(74, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(75, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(76, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(77, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(78, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(79, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(80, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(81, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(82, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(83, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(84, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(85, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(86, 1) = "Seals"
    MatType1(87, 1) = "Seals"
    MatType1(88, 1) = "Seals"
    MatType1(89, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(90, 1) = "Round Bar"
    MatType1(91, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(92, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(93, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(94, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(95, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(96, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(97, 1) = "Everything Else"
    MatType1(98, 1) = "Everything Else"

    ' Find the address of the caller (the cell where the address is)
    Dim clr As Range
    Set clr = Application.Caller

    ' Find the row only of the caller
    Dim FRow As String
    FRow = clr.Row

    ' Search the range A1 to Z1 for vA, vC, vD, and vE
    Dim rng As Range
      Set rng = Range("A1:Z1")

      Dim vA As String
      Dim vC As String
      Dim vD As String
      Dim vE As String
      Dim lA As String
      Dim lC As String
      Dim lD As String
      Dim lE As String

      vA = "Quantity"
      vC = "Thick. / Dia."
      vD = "Width / #-ft"
      vE = "Length"

      For Each c In Range("A1:Z1").Cells
            If c.Value = vA Then
                lA = Left(Replace(c.Address, "$", ""), 1)
            End If

            If c.Value = vC Then
                lC = Left(Replace(c.Address, "$", ""), 1)
            End If

            If c.Value = vD Then
                lD = Left(Replace(c.Address, "$", ""), 1)
            End If

            If c.Value = vE Then
                lE = Left(Replace(c.Address, "$", ""), 1)
            End If
      Next c

    ' Setting the values from the corresponding ranges to the following variables
    Dim qty As String
    Dim thk As String
    Dim width As String
    Dim length As String

    qty = Range(lA & FRow).Value
    thk = Range(lC & FRow).Value
    width = Range(lD & FRow).Value
    length = Range(lE & FRow).Value

    For i = 0 To UBound(MatType1, 1)
        If matl = MatType1(i, 0) Then
            flag = 1
            matl = MatType1(i, 0)
            matlDes = CStr(MatType1(i, 1))
        End If
    Next i

    If flag = 1 Then
        If matlDes = "Plate / Flat Bar" Then
            MatType = Round(thk * width * length * 0.0000174 * qty, 2)
        End If


        If matlDes = "Structural" Then
            MatType = Round((length / 304.8) * width * qty, 2)
        End If

        If matlDes = "Round Bar" Then
            MatType = Round(((3.14 * (length * (thk / 2) * (thk / 2))) * 0.0000174) * qty, 2)
        End If

        If matlDes = "Aluminum Plate / Flat Bar" Then
            MatType = Round(((thk * width * length) * 0.00000595) * qty, 2)
        End If

        If matlDes = "Aluminum Round Bar" Then
            MatType = Round(((3.14 * (length * (thk / 2) * (thk / 2))) * 0.00000595) * qty, 2)
        End If

        If matlDes = "Brass Round Bar" Then
            MatType = Round(((3.14 * (length * (thk / 2) * (thk / 2))) * 0.00001851883) * qty, 2)
        End If

         If matlDes = "Brass Plate / Flat Bar" Then
            MatType = Round(((thk * width * length) * 0.00001851883) * qty, 2)
        End If

         If matlDes = "UHMW Plate / Flat Bar" Then
            MatType = Round(thk * width * length * 0.03 * qty, 2)
        End If

         If matlDes = "UHMW Round Bar" Then
            MatType = Round((3.14 * (length / 25.4) * (((thk / 2) / 25.4) * ((thk / 2) / 25.4)) * qty) * 0.03, 2)
        End If

         If matlDes = "Seals" Then
            MatType = Round((length / 304.8) * qty, 2)
        End If

         If matlDes = "Bar Grating" Then
            MatType = Round((thk * (width / 304.8) * (length / 304.8)) * qty, 2)
        End If

         If matlDes = "Everything Else" Then
            MatType = Round(qty)
        End If


    End If



End Function
```

Any help in getting all the tabs to recalculate when a cell's value changes and/or opening the workbook would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your calculation option set to automatic??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't linking your code to the calling worksheet - your unqualified calls like

```
Set rng = Range("A1:Z1")
```

will always refer to whichever sheet happens to be active, and not to the sheet with the formula (unless that's the activesheet...)

You need to do something like this at the top of your function:

```
Dim sht As WorkSheet
Set sht = Application.Caller.Worksheet
```

Then use `sht` to qualify every singe Range/Cells call within the UDF

See [What is the default scope of worksheets and cells and range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439376/what-is-the-default-scope-of-worksheets-and-cells-and-range) for what the default "scope" is for calls to `Range`/`Cells`

Answer (score 0):

Use: `Application.volatile` at the top of your code, it will cause your function to recalculate anytime you update/refresh your workbook

Answer (score 0):

A UDF (or any Excel function) recalculates when the value of one or more of its parameters change.  You should pass ranges as parameters to the UDF rather than hard coding those ranges into the code.

As a template, consider changing to

```
Public Function MatType(matl As String, qty As Range, thk As Range, width As Range, length As Range) As Double
```

<sup>You can use `Application.Volitile` for force it to recalc on every recalculation, but that's inefficient and unnecessary in this case.  If you *do* go this way you'll need to follow Tim's advice to fix worksheet scoping</sup>