# Setting Range Results in Application Defined or Object Defined Error, two methods? VBA

Tags: vba, excel, range

When setting a range, and the active worksheet is not = to the reference I get an

> Application Defined Object Defined Error

using this method below:

```
Set Rng = Worksheets("Worksheet2").Range(Cells(2,2),Cells(2,3))
```

But why does it work when I use this method:

```
Set Rng = Range(Worksheets("Worksheet2").Cells(2,2),Worksheets("Worksheet2").Cells(2,3))
```

Just trying to understand why exactly the last method works, but the first does not.

Comment: Cells() in your first example refers to the activesheet, which might not be Worksheet2.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439376/what-is-the-default-scope-of-worksheets-and-cells-and-range/28439984#28439984

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are breaking the range, as far as both `Cells` and `Range` should be refered to the same Parent. If you do not refer any of them, their parent is the activesheet:

Thus either refer the parent explicitly for both of them:

```
With Worksheets("worksheets2")
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(2, 3))
End With
```

or leave it empty for both of them (thus it would be the ActiveSheet):

```
Set Rng = Range(Cells(2,2),Cells(2,3))
```

---

To make this work `Set Rng = Worksheets("Worksheet2").Range(Cells(2,2),Cells(2,3))`, you have to make sure that `Worksheets2` is your activesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Because you cannot have two different references for the worksheet and the cells. So it whould be like

```
Set Rng = Worksheets("Worksheet2").Range(Worksheets("Worksheet2").Cells(2, 2), Worksheets("Worksheet2").Cells(2, 3))
```