# VBA-Excel macro only works on current sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Hi all pretty new to VBA here and I am struggling to get my macro to work on multiple sheets. I basically want to hide and unhide columns "B-AB" if they have an "X" in row 8. Currently the macro only works on the active sheet and not the active workbook. Thanks!

```
Sub roll()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim c As Range


For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

With sh

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Columns("B:AB").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False


        For Each c In Range("b8:ab8").Cells
            If c.Value = "X" Then
            c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End If

        Next c
            End With

Next sh

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439376/what-is-the-default-scope-of-worksheets-and-cells-and-range/28439984#28439984  You aren't using your With block

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `.` in front of the range object that are assigned to the sheet noted in the with:

```
Sub roll()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim c As Range


For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

With sh

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    .Columns("B:AB").Hidden = False


        For Each c In .Range("b8:ab8").Cells
            If c.Value = "X" Then
                c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next c
    End With

Next sh

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works like a charm. I am also wondering if it wasn't working as well since my code wasn't aligned like the way you had it. My last end with wasn't indented aligned with the ".columns" section of code?

Comment: Alignment has nothing to do with how it works. Just looks better

Comment: Thanks so much Scott!