# Ordering data on a set column on four sheets in a single workbook

Tags: excel, vba

This program is supposed to order dates in descending order from N14 to N66.

The program works as intended on the first sheet but not on the other three. The specified area is the same on all four sheets (N14 - N66) and the data to arrange is dates on all four sheets.

I attempted to place the code for each individual sheet, this had the same result.
I tried looping it for sheets 2-4.

I looked at a similar problem
[VBA-Excel macro only works on current sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066878/vba-excel-macro-only-works-on-current-sheet).
I get

> Compile Error: Invalid or unqualified reference

The main program is in a module as a subroutine called "OrderDates" (program below). This subroutine is called for each sheet (in "Microsoft Excel Objects Folder"). Using this structure, the program works as intended on the 1 sheet only.

```vb
Sub OrderDates()
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N:N")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("N14").Sort key1:=Range("N66"), _
          Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
          OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=True, _
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
End Sub
```

Calling the subroutine when a change is made to the worksheet (this is called for each sheet separately in the Microsoft excel Objects folder).

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call OrderDates
End Sub
```

Comment: So, you have such `Change` events code in the four sheets you want processing. Is this understanding correct? If so, you need to process the sheet where the event calling the sub exists. Is this a correct understanding, too?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I call the subroutine in all four sheets. Thank you for the pointer, I'll try processing the sheet when the subroutine is called.

Comment: Then, did you try the solution I proposed in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted solution. Not answering my clarification question, the solution assumes that the four sheets in discussion contain a similare `Event` code and you want the called `Sub` processing the respective triggered event sheet. The called common `Sub` must have a parameter to know where from the call came:

```
Sub OrderDates(Target as Range)
    dim ws as Worksheet
    set ws = Target.parent
    If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range("N:N")) Is Nothing Then
        ws.Range("N14").Sort key1:=ws.Range("N66"), _
        Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=True, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
End Sub
```

`Range("N:N")` refers the **active sheet** and it must be fully qualified.

The `Event` code should look as:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Application.EnableEvents = False
    OrderDates Target
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

To 'inform' the called sub what range should be processed...

Comment: Thank you, this would work but I keep getting a Run-time error 1004. According to the error message, all merged cells need to be the same size. I oddly only encounter this error when I apply the event code to a sheet other than the initial one despite that all 4 sheets should (in theory) be the same.

Comment: @Ganz Hunslet G2 On which code line is the error raised? Does the code work on the other three worksheets? Which range area has merged cells? Merged between columns or between rows?

Comment: The debugger highlights rows 5 to 8. The code works on worksheet 1 and generates an error for worksheets 2-4. The merged cells exist between A12/13 and AA12/13 and these are merged rows. Additionally, there is also a merged row on 2H/I, where H and I have been merged into a single cell. However, none of these merges affect column N.

Comment: Is it a problem to unmerge the cells in discussion? It can be done in code. If not, ai am afraid Excel will not sort it. Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/error-sort-a-range-merged-cell) to better understand what is it about and what can be done...

Comment: Thank you for your time, I've managed to get it working now. The problem was with the other 3 sheets and not with your program. Thank you again.