# Excel VBA. When is it necesary to activate a Sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

A general answer would be perfect, b
I have this simple code, that only works if Sheet2 is active when running the macro.

Otherwise it gives an error "defined by the application or object":

```
Sub PasteArray()
Dim arr(1 To 3) As Variant
Dim n As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

arr(1) = 4
arr(2) = 6
arr(3) = 8
n = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1
Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(n, 1)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
End Sub
```

It works if I activate the sheet first, but that requires that I save the current active sheet to come back at the end.

```
Sub PasteArray()
Dim arr(1 To 3) As Variant
Dim n As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

arr(1) = 4
arr(2) = 6
arr(3) = 8
n = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(n, 1)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
ws.Activate
```

Is it always necesary to do something like this?
I am pretty sure that I have seen some code in which changes to cells in an unactive sheet were made.

Thank you

Comment: For all intents and purposes, it is **never** important to activate a worksheet unless you want to show something to the person in the chair.

Comment: See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Also see [What is the default scope of worksheets and cells and range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439376/what-is-the-default-scope-of-worksheets-and-cells-and-range/28439984) for why it might *seem* necessary from your code example.

Comment: ... and [Is the . in .Range necessary when defined by .Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368220/is-the-in-range-necessary-when-defined-by-cells)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to activate a sheet really ever unless you want the user to see something.

You receive an error because of your references, always remember to include `Sheet` or `Worksheet` with `Ranges`:

```
Sub PasteArray()
    Dim arr(1 To 3) As Variant
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    arr(1) = 4
    arr(2) = 6
    arr(3) = 8
    n = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(n, 1)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
End Sub
```

Added `Sheets("Sheets2")` before the `Cells` parts

Honestly would suggest googling how to use `With` statement in VBA, it would help lots in situations like this

Comment: `Sheets` is an implicit reference to `ActiveWorkbook`, and repeatedly hammering the `Sheets` collection to find `"Sheet2"` is extremely poor from a performance standpoint - It should either be stored or referenced from a `With` block.  This code is only marginally better than the OP's.

Comment: @Comintern great points, but this is why I mentioned the googling of `With` above. Also just wanted to demonstrate why there was an error and this way makes it easy to visualize for somebody who appears to obviously not have much experience with VBA