# Set Range doesn't work with Cells() inside

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code in which I set those two ranges:

```
Set ColorSAP = SAP_Comparison.Range("C3:AG19")
Set ColorPlan = Production_Plan.Worksheets("Schedule").Range(Cells(4, 
MonthS), Cells(20, (MonthE - 1)))
```

`MonthS` and `MonthE` are integers.

`Production_plan` is a workbook.

`SAP_Comparison` is a workbook.

I have no idea why I get a error for the second but not for the first since they are very similar.
I have even tested easier cases and this kind of usage do work.

```
Error: Run-Time '1004'
Application-defined or object-defined error.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Production_Plan is a Workbook

Comment: SAP_Comparison is a Sheet

Answer (score 2):

Unqualified Cells refers to the ActiveSheet, which will raise an error if that's not "Schedule"

You need something like

```
With Production_Plan.Worksheets("Schedule")
    Set ColorPlan = .Range(.Cells(4, MonthS), .Cells(20, (MonthE - 1)))
End With
```

or

```
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Production_Plan.Worksheets("Schedule")
Set ColorPlan = sht.Range(sht.Cells(4, MonthS), sht.Cells(20, (MonthE - 1)))
```

[What is the default scope of worksheets and cells and range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439376/what-is-the-default-scope-of-worksheets-and-cells-and-range/28439984#28439984)

Comment: What is the difference between using ".Range" and ".Cells" and "Range" and "Cells"?

Comment: I mean `Cells(x, y)` (unqualified with a worksheet reference) vs. `Production_Plan.Worksheets("Schedule").Cells(x, y)` (qualified with a specific worksheet in a specific workbook)

Comment: When you use a `With` block the leading `.` on (eg) `.Cells()` "connects" that to the object specified by the `With` line

Answer (score 0):

You could use Cells to get address out of and feed Range with:

```
Set ColorPlan = Production_Plan.Worksheets("Schedule").Range(Cells(4, MonthS).Address & “:” & Cells(20, (MonthE - 1)).Address)
```

This way you only have one “true” Range object and it’s completely qualified