# Range Only Works When Called from the Referenced Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, range

I've got a macro assigned to two buttons, each on a different worksheet: "Print Page 1" and "Optimization". The macro takes information from the first to know how many times to copy a range the second.

When called while "Optimization" is active, the code works perfectly, but when called with the "Print Page 1" worksheet active, a "1004 error: Application-defined or object-defined error" is produced on the line that copies the ranges. See below:

```
Sub Range_Tester()

Dim PrintRow, WallQty

WallQty = Worksheets("Print Page 1").Cells(24, 4)
PrintRow = 20

While WallQty > 1
    Worksheets("Optimization").Range(Cells(PrintRow - 1, 2), Cells(PrintRow - 1, 4)).Copy Worksheets("Optimization").Range(Cells(PrintRow, 2), Cells(PrintRow, 4))
    WallQty = WallQty - 1
    PrintRow = PrintRow + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

I think the problem is my range syntax; if I replace

```
Worksheets("Optimization").Range(Cells(PrintRow - 1, 2), Cells(PrintRow - 1, 4)).Copy Worksheets("Optimization").Range(Cells(PrintRow, 2), Cells(PrintRow, 4))
```

with

```
Worksheets("Optimization").Cells(PrintRow - 1, 2).Copy Worksheets("Optimization").Cells(PrintRow, 2)
Worksheets("Optimization").Cells(PrintRow - 1, 3).Copy Worksheets("Optimization").Cells(PrintRow, 3)
Worksheets("Optimization").Cells(PrintRow - 1, 4).Copy Worksheets("Optimization").Cells(PrintRow, 4)
```

The info copies flawlessly regardless of which worksheet is active.

My apologies for asking what is probably a stupidly simple question, I just haven't had any luck finding info on properly defining ranges that change locations.

Comment: You must apply the same parent to the `Cells` in the `Range` as the `Range`:  `Worksheets("Optimization").Range(Worksheets("Optimization").Cells(...`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439376/what-is-the-default-scope-of-worksheets-and-cells-and-range/28439984#28439984

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cells` being unqualified, implicitly refers to `ActiveSheet`, because that code isn't written in a worksheet module. If it was, then unqualified `Cells` would be like `Me.Cells`. Anywhere else, it's `ActiveSheet.Cells`.

Always explicitly qualify `Worksheet` member calls with a proper `Worksheet` object, and you'll avoid this problem.

```
Worksheets("Optimization").Range(Cells(PrintRow - 1, 2), Cells(PrintRow - 1, 4)).Copy Worksheets("Optimization").Range(Cells(PrintRow, 2), Cells(PrintRow, 4))
```

Here, you're invoking `.Range` against `Worksheets("Optimization")`, but then parameterizing it with `Cells(PrintRow - 1, 2)`, which *may* belong to another sheet (whatever `ActiveSheet` is). When it does, things blow up.

Capture the `Worksheets("Optimization")` reference into a `With` block variable (or a plain old local variable):

```
With Worksheets("Optimization")
    .Range(.Cells(PrintRow - 1, 2), .Cells(PrintRow - 1, 4)).Copy .Range(.Cells(PrintRow, 2), .Cells(PrintRow, 4))
End With
```

Notice the `.` dereferencing operator, which makes `.Cells` work off `Worksheets("Optimization")` like the `.Range` call, ensuring everything is pulled from the same sheet.

Comment: Wooooowww! That makes sense! It surprises me that the Worksheet qualification would not extend to `.Cells` , though; qualifying a range in one worksheet and cells a different worksheet hurts my newbie brain, but it must have some application.

Comment: @Approx. (great username!) grab yourself a copy of [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck). It will do wonders for your coding skills. I'm a very happy user (and unofficial QA tester). Mathieu is the project owner and a heavy contributor.