# Setting Excel Worksheet to a Variable, and calling the variable in a different sub

Tags: excel, vba, variables, worksheet-function

I've been working on another program where I am taking specific data from a worksheet, and paste it into a certain sheet on a workbook, depending on what the part type is that is found on the data in the first worksheet.

To be able to decipher which sheet will be called up, I had to write If statements to determine, based on the "part type" cell value, which sheet would be called and could be pasted into. Since there is approximately 4 subs involved (copy and pasting the date, the time, part type and the specific pressing force), I had `IF` statements in every single sub, and it would just call the subs individually.

To shorten this, and just call the "Correct Worksheet" at the beginning of every sub without having to use another `IF` statement, I've been trying to set the Worksheet to a variable, as you'll see below:

```
With ActiveWorkbook

   If CaseBRH = True Then

      CorrectFile = Sheets("Case B Left Hand")

   ElseIf CaseBLH = True Then

      CorrectFile = Sheets("Case B Right Hand")

   ElseIf Feedshaft = True Then

      CorrectFile = Sheets("Feedshaft")

   End If
```

CorrectFile is a variable that I've defined as a Public before the first Sub routine.

Basically what I did was use a StrComp and Find if CaseBLH, CaseBRH, or Feedshaft is true, and that part was working up until I made these changes.

The problem is now that when I get to a line like this one:

```
Workbooks("Consolidated Diagramm Data.xlsx").Activate

CorrectFile.Activate

Range("C1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

It jumps out of the sub completely after completing the `CorrectFile.Activate` line and goes onto the next sub, and it does not call the correct worksheet. Any suggestions?

Below is the entire Module:

```
Public Path As String
Public Counter As Integer
Public LHCounter As Integer
Public RHCounter As Integer
Public FeedshaftCounter As Integer
Public NameFile As Workbook
Public Feedsft As String
Public RightHand As String
Public LeftHand As String
Public Feedshaft As Boolean
Public CaseBRH As Boolean
Public CaseBLH As Boolean
Public Celltxt As String
Public MyFolder As String 'Path collected from the folder picker dialog
Public MyFile As String 'Filename obtained by DIR function
Public wbk As Workbook 'Used to loop through each workbook
Public thisWb As Workbook
Public CorrectFile As Worksheet

Sub Consolidate_Diagramms_Data()

Set NameFile = Workbooks.Add

Dim wb As Workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

NameFile.SaveAs FileName:="C:\DataAnalyzation\Consolidated Diagramm Data.xlsx"

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Case B Left Hand"

Worksheets.Add().Name = "Case B Right Hand"

Worksheets.Add().Name = "Feedshaft"

Call AllWorkbooks

End Sub

Sub AllWorkbooks()

Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook

On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Opens the folder picker dialog to allow user selection

MsgBox "Please select the folder from which you wish to consolidate your data."

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

.Title = "Please select a folder"

.Show

.AllowMultiSelect = False

   If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then 'If no folder is selected, abort

MsgBox "You did not select a folder"

      Exit Sub

   End If

MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\" 'Assign selected folder to MyFolder

End With

Counter = 0

LHCounter = 0

RHCounter = 0

FeedshaftCounter = 0

MyFile = Dir(MyFolder) 'DIR gets the first file of the folder

'Loop through all files in a folder until DIR cannot find anymore

Do While MyFile <> ""

    Counter = Counter + 1

    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyFolder & MyFile)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

EventState = Application.EnableEvents
Application.EnableEvents = False

CalcState = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

PageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

Feedsft = "Feed Shaft"
RightHand = "Case B Right Hand"
LeftHand = "Case  B Left Hand"

Celltxt = Range("D2").Value

If StrComp(Celltxt, Feedsft, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

    CaseBLH = False
    CaseBRH = False
    Feedshaft = True
    FeedshaftCounter = FeedshaftCounter + 1

ElseIf StrComp(Celltxt, LeftHand, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

    Feeshaft = False
    CaseBRH = False
    CaseBLH = True
    LHCounter = LHCounter + 1

ElseIf StrComp(Celltxt, RightHand, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

    Feedshaft = False
    CaseBLH = False
    CaseBRH = True
    RHCounter = RHCounter + 1

End If

With ActiveWorkbook

If CaseBRH = True Then

    Set CorrectFile = Sheets("Case B Left Hand")

ElseIf CaseBLH = True Then

    Set CorrectFile = Sheets("Case B Right Hand")

ElseIf Feedshaft = True Then

    Set CorrectFile = Sheets("Feedshaft")

End If

End With

If Feedshaft = True And FeedshaftCounter = 1 Then 'If it is a Feedshaft and this is the first part of that part type

    Call Copy_Position
    Call Paste_Position
    Call Copy_Paste_Date
    Call Copy_PartType
    Call Paste_PartType

ElseIf CaseBLH = True And LHCounter = 1 Then 'If it is a Case B LH and this is the first part of that part type

    Call Copy_Position
    Call Paste_Position
    Call Copy_Paste_Date
    Call Copy_PartType
    Call Paste_PartType

ElseIf CaseBRH = True And RHCounter = 1 Then 'If it is a Case B RH and this is the first part of that part type

    Call Copy_Position
    Call Paste_Position
    Call Copy_Paste_Date
    Call Copy_PartType
    Call Paste_PartType

End If

    Call Copy_Paste_Force

wbk.Close savechanges:=False

MyFile = Dir 'DIR gets the next file in the folder

Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox ("A total of " & Counter & " files have been consolidated. This includes " & LHCounter & " Left Hand Part(s), " & RHCounter & " Right Hand Part(s) and " & FeedshaftCounter & " Feedshaft(s).")

End Sub

Sub Copy_Position()

    Range("C4").Activate
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Copy 'Copies the Part Type displayed in Cell C4

End Sub

Sub Paste_Position()

If Range("C4") = "" Then

MsgBox ("There is no data in this file") 'Checks for an empty value in Cell C4

End If

Workbooks("Consolidated Diagramm Data.xlsx").Activate 'Activates Workbook

CorrectFile.Range("C1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True 'Pastes Position data into a Row, starting at Column C

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub


Sub Copy_Paste_Date()

Workbooks(MyFile).Activate 'Activates the Data Sheet

ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Copy 'Copies the Date

Workbooks("Consolidated Diagramm Data.xlsx").Activate 'Activates the final Workbook

CorrectFile.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll 'Pastes the Date into "A2"

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Sub Copy_PartType()

        Workbooks(MyFile).Activate 'Activates Data Sheet
        ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Copy 'Copies part type

End Sub

Sub Paste_PartType()

If Range("D2") = "" Then

MsgBox ("There is no data in this file") 'Checks for no values in "D2"

End If

Workbooks("Consolidated Diagramm Data.xlsx").Activate 'Activates the Correct

CorrectFile.Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll 'Pastes the part type into "B2"

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub


Sub Copy_Paste_Force()

Dim CR As Long
Dim Cpy As Range


Workbooks(MyFile).Activate 'Calls up the Data Sheet
Range("D4").Activate
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Copy 'Copies Force Values

If Range("D4") = "" Then

MsgBox ("There is no data in this file") 'Checks for no values in "D4"

End If

Workbooks("Consolidated Diagramm Data.xlsx").Activate

If Feedshaft = True And FeedshaftCounter = 1 Then 'If it is Feedshaft and no parts have been pasted

    GoTo PasteInitial

ElseIf Feedshaft = True And FeedshaftCounter > 1 Then 'If it is Feedshaft and one part has already been pasted

    GoTo PasteAfter

ElseIf CaseBLH = True And LHCounter = 1 Then 'If it is Case B LH and no parts have been pasted

    GoTo PasteInitial

ElseIf CaseBLH = True And LHCounter > 1 Then 'If it is Case B LH and one part has already been pasted

    GoTo PasteAfter

ElseIf CaseBRH = True And RHCounter = 1 Then 'If it is Case B RH and no parts have been pasted

    GoTo PasteInitial

ElseIf CaseBRH = True And RHCounter > 1 Then 'If it is Case B RH and one part has already been pasted

    GoTo PasteAfter

End If

PasteInitial: 'Pastes the first force values into Column C underneath the vertical position

    Range("C2").Activate
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    GoTo Nd

PasteAfter: 'After the first force value is Pasted, this searches for the last row, offsets, and pastes into the next empty row

    CR = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Range(CR).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    GoTo Nd

Nd:

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete but can you pass the worksheet into the second sub as a parameter?

Comment: @user10735198 I'm not sure if it does pass it on. It's a public variable, so I would assume so.

Comment: `CorrectFile = Sheets("Case B Left Hand")` shouldn't even compile. Since a worksheet is not a primitive data-type, you need to write `set CorrectFile = Sheets("Case B Left Hand")`. Anyways, where have you declared the CorrectFile variable?

Comment: Please learn to indent your code - makes it much more readable. Btw your With statement is redundant as you have no dots.

Comment: @JoshEller It's a public variable declared above the first Sub.

Comment: @JoshEller if `CorrectFile` isn't an object type, implicit let-coercion of the default member assigns to whatever the default member is - if that's an object with a default member, that's the value the LHS argument is assigned to.. if there's no default member (as is the case for a `Worksheet`), it still happily compiles if LHS is `Variant`, but then `Option Explicit` is useless, no member call against `CorrectFile` can get intellisense, and any typo results in runtime error 438 - but does compile. If OP's code runs, I suspect they have `Dim CorrectFile` [As Variant]. Wrong, but legal.

Comment: NoahThomas how and where is `CorrectFile` declared? It should be `Private CorrectFile As Worksheet` - near `Option Explicit`, and then with that you'll find that the `Set` keyword is missing, as @JoshEller mentions.

Comment: Aso you probably don't need to `Activate` it at all. Qualify that `Range` call with `CorrectFile` (a bad name for a worksheet BTW - it's not a file at all): `CorrectFile.Range("C1").PasteSpecial ...` should work without needing to `Activate` the sheet.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Refer to my response to Josh, I said it's declared Publicly before the first sub. I have it currently declared as a Worksheet. I'll also run what you put through, and I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: How about you [edit] your post so that it includes all the relevant code instead? Why is it `Public`? Is it used anywhere outside the module it's declared in? If it's `As Worksheet`, then the code you're showing can't possibly run past either `CorrectFile =` assignment; they're all illegal.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yeah that's where I'm at, I don't know how to set the "CorrectFile" to the Excel sheet. I've changed it now so it Sets CorrectFile to the correct worksheet. The only reason I'm using CorrectFile is because at one point I was using several Files instead of Worksheets. And it's public because I have to use it in a total of 6 sub routines.

Comment: If the 6 procedures are all in the same module then it doesn't need to be public. Also if the 6 procedures all have the same entry point then you can pass the worksheet as a parameter instead - no need for a module-level variable. Point being, there's not enough context in the post as it stands, to give you a good, useful answer IMO.

Comment: Please, [edit] your post. Comments are for requesting clarifications; the post itself should be edited in response, to include the clarifications.

Comment: As it stands the answer would be identical to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513). If that doesn't answer your question, please read [mcve] and [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I am new to this forum, so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: No problem. Writing a good, focused question is *hard* - that's why I linked to [mcve]... this time with emphasis on the *minimal* part: we don't need to see your entire code, just enough to reproduce the specific problem you're having. That said I encourage you to read the Q&A I linked earlier about avoiding select/activate, and I'll link to [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53599691/1188513) that explains why unqualified `Range` calls are dangerous and tend to create exactly the problem you're having (aka "works against the wrong sheet"), if not outright runtime errors.

Comment: I thought it might be worth pointing out that a `with` loop that references the `activeworkbook` doesn't do much, since excel will assume the `activeworkbook` if an unqualified reference to `sheets/worksheets` is made. Also in regards to this line: `Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook` if you wish to reference the workbook that contains the macro, `ThisWorkbook` would work as well