# Checking for Minimum Value in column, and copying all the data after that minimum value

Tags: excel, vba, variables, worksheet-function

So I'm still working on pulling and analyzing data from the same sheets that I've asked about before, but I've been asked to re-evaluate my approach.

Refer to here for a bit of a background on what I am doing: [Setting Excel Worksheet to a Variable, and calling the variable in a different sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618389/setting-excel-worksheet-to-a-variable-and-calling-the-variable-in-a-different-s)

Now I have to find the minimum value that can be found in my column, and then copy all the data in that column that appears after it.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
Public Path As String
Public Counter As Integer
Public NameFile As Workbook
Public Celltxt As String 'Checks cell value in D2, used to compare to Strings to confirm part type
Public MyFolder As String 'Path collected from the folder picker dialog
Public MyFile As String 'Filename obtained by DIR function
Public wbk As Workbook 'Used to loop through each workbook
Public thisWb As Workbook
Public MasterFile As String
Public Min As Variant

Sub Consolidate_Diagramms_Data()

Dim wb As Workbook

Dim TestStr As String

TestStr = ""

TestStr = Dir("C:\DataAnalyzation\Consolidated Diagramm Data.xlsx")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

If TestStr = "" Then

    Set NameFile = Workbooks.Add

    NameFile.SaveAs Filename:="C:\DataAnalyzation\Consolidated Diagramm Data.xlsx"

    Range("A1").Value = "Part Number"

    Range("B1").Value = "Date"

    Range("C1").Value = "Time"

    Range("D1").Value = "Part Type"

    Range("E1").Value = "Comment"

    Range("F1").Value = "Zero"

    Else

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\DataAnalyzation\Consolidated Diagramm Data.xlsx"

    Range("A1").Value = "Part Number"

    Range("B1").Value = "Date"

    Range("C1").Value = "Time"

    Range("D1").Value = "Part Type"

    Range("E1").Value = "Comment"

    Range("F1").Value = "Zero"

End If

MasterFile = "C:\DataAnalyzation\Consolidated Diagramm Data.xlsx"

Call AllWorkbooks

End Sub

Sub AllWorkbooks()

Dim LastRow As Long

Dim minRange As Variant

Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook

'On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Opens the folder picker dialog to allow user selection

MsgBox "Please select the folder from which you wish to consolidate your data."

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

.Title = "Please select a folder"

.Show

.AllowMultiSelect = False

   If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then 'If no folder is selected, abort

MsgBox "You did not select a folder"

      Exit Sub

   End If

MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\" 'Assign selected folder to MyFolder

End With

Counter = 0

LHCounter = 0

RHCounter = 0

FeedshaftCounter = 0

MyFile = Dir(MyFolder) 'DIR gets the first file of the folder

'Loop through all files in a folder until DIR cannot find anymore

Do While MyFile <> ""

    LastRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    Counter = Counter + 1

    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFolder & MyFile)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

EventState = Application.EnableEvents
Application.EnableEvents = False

CalcState = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

PageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Copy Part Number, Date, Time, Part Type, and Comment

    Workbooks(MyFile).Activate 'Activates the Data Sheet

    If Range("B1").Value = "" Then

        GoTo Nd

    End If

    ActiveSheet.Range("A2:E2").Copy 'Copies the Part Number, Date, Time and Part Type

    'Paste Part Number, Date, Time, Part Type, and Comment

    Workbooks("Consolidated Diagramm Data.xlsx").Activate 'Activates the final Workbook

    Range("A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll 'Pastes the Date into "A2"

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Copy Force

    Workbooks(MyFile).Activate

    Range("D4").Activate

    minRange = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Sheets(1).Range("D4:D500"))

    minRange.Activate

    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Copy

    Workbooks("Consolidated Diagramm Data.xlsx").Activate

    Range("F" & LastRow).Activate

    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    GoTo Nd

    'End of Copy/Paste coding

Nd:

wbk.Close savechanges:=False

MyFile = Dir 'DIR gets the next file in the folder

Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox ("A total of " & Counter & " files have been consolidated.")

End Sub
```

The problem that I am running into is that I cannot seem to be able to find the minimum value, activate that cell, and copy all the data in that column that follows after it.

At the lines:

```
    minRange = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Sheets(1).Range("D4:D500"))

    minRange.Activate
```

I am getting a "Runtime Error '424': Object Required" fault.

Below is the updated portion of my code where I'm searching for the minimum value. I'm currently getting a "Run-time 1004: Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class".

```
Workbooks(MyFile).Activate

    Range("D4").Activate

    Set myRng = Range("D4:D" & Rows.Count)

    minValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(myRng)

    myRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(minValue, myRng, 0)

    Range(myRow, myRng).Activate

    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Copy

    Workbooks("Consolidated Diagramm Data.xlsx").Activate

    Range("F" & LastRow).Activate

    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    GoTo Nd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will give you the row of the minimum value (assuming there is only one):

```
Dim myRng As Range
Dim myRow as Long
Dim minValue as Long
Set myRng = Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count)
minValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(myRng)
MyRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(minValue, myRng, 0)
```

Comment: This is the fault I am getting with what you suggested:  "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed". When I hit Debug, it goes to the line "Set myRng = Range("D4:D500" & Rows.Count)

Comment: It's giving me a Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class. Is this the non-breaking error that I've heard about?

Comment: Not sure why you are getting an error: my snippet works fine here. I just noticed you changed `Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count)` to `Range("D4:D500" & Rows.Count)` (it should be `Range("D4:D" & Rows.Count)` or `Range("D4:D500")` Did yo make any other changes? you may want to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53658350/edit) with the updated code

Comment: Yeah, I made that change when you said you had a typo. I edited my question by posting the edited code to reflect the changes.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code? Also, I notice you `Activate` a lot of stuff. You may want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)