# VBA code doesn't run when I call it automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro named `Splittext` that is called when there is a change in cell "B4" of sheet `Macro Process` it doesn't work when I call it but it works when I manually run it. There is no error in the code

```
Sub splitText()
    Dim wsS1 As Worksheet 'Sheet1
    Dim textstring As String, warray() As String, counter As Integer, strg As String

    Set wsS1 = Sheets("OUTPUT 1")
    wsS1.Activate

    textstring = Range("A2").Value
    warray() = Split(textstring, ">")

    For counter = LBound(warray) To UBound(warray)
        strg = warray(counter)
        Cells(counter + 3, 1).Value = Trim(strg)
    Next counter

    textstring = Range("B2").Value
    warray() = Split(textstring, ">")

    For counter = LBound(warray) To UBound(warray)
        strg = warray(counter)
        Cells(counter + 3, 2).Value = Trim(strg)  
    Next counter

    textstring = Range("C2").Value
    warray() = Split(textstring, ">")

    For counter = LBound(warray) To UBound(warray)
        strg = warray(counter)
        Cells(counter + 3, 3).Value = Trim(strg)
    Next counter
End Sub
```

This code is supposed to separate the text present in the Cells ("A2")("B2")("C2") of sheet "OUTPUT 1"

This is how I am calling the code

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Set Target = Range("B4")
    If Target.Value = "Completed" Then
        Call splitText
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly how are you calling it automatically?

Comment: @TimWilliams please check the question i've updated it with the code that i am using to call the macro

Comment: None of your code refers to specific worksheets - a good start would be to qualify all of your range/cells references so they refer to the correct worksheet.  Which sheet are you monitoring for changes? All of them?

Comment: FWIW You have code that is essentially repeating at the top which, I think, with another outer loop from 1 to 3 could reduce the inner looping to just one block.   For i = 1 to 3: textstring =  Cells(2,i).Value  :  Cells(counter + 3, i)   '<== key replacement lines

Comment: you mean i need to define a worksheet on which the code needs to run??? @TimWilliams

Comment: Yes - otherwise it just defaults to whichever sheet is active.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439376/what-is-the-default-scope-of-worksheets-and-cells-and-range/28439984#28439984

Comment: Ill try and get back to you

Comment: @TimWilliams i've tried that as well still it didnt work even after defining the worksheet

Comment: In that case it would be useful to edit your question to update your code with the version which specifies the worksheet.

Comment: updated the code @TimWilliams please check

Comment: Huge problems in code: (1) Calling `SheetChange` and then setting the `Target` without checking what cell actually changed.  (2) activating sheets. (3) not properly qualifying ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what sheet you're monitoring for changes, but this worked for me:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Set Target = sh.Range("B4")
    If Target.Value = "Completed" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        splitText
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub


Sub splitText()
    Dim warray() As String, i As Long, c As Range
    For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OUTPUT 1").Range("A2:C2").Cells
        warray = Split(c.Value, ">")
        For i = LBound(warray) To UBound(warray)
            c.Offset(i + 1, 0).Value = Trim(warray(i))
        Next i
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: finally ...Thanks! ...it worked ..Thank you so much for your patience and help!

Comment: Tim, I know it was in the OP - but why have a `SheetChange` and then set *`Target`* to a fixed address that is likely to be anything but the target? I am really surprised you did not pick this up! (Instead: `If Target.Address = "B4"` etc).

Comment: I did pick it up but there's some potential reasons for why it might be that way so...

Comment: Tim, from OP "that is called when there is a change in cell "B4" of sheet " - so the event handler should check to see if that is the cell that is changed - not force the issue. The only thing I can think of is if B4 is changed through formula but then some other criteria must be checked to see if there really is a change. The code as currently stands will run ***every time there is a change in any worksheet*** as long as B4 = completed.

Comment: The comment above the code was a hint for the OP that they had a bit of work to do to make it right.  B4 is right under the cells being split, and the process would quite likely overwrite whatever is in B4...