# Setting the Range object with Cells on a different Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have been creating Ranges with Cells for a while but always on the selected worksheet.  I use the following syntax:

```
Dim r as Range
Set r = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 2))
```

This has always worked.

I am not trying to select a range on a different sheet using the following syntax:

```
Dim r as Range
Set r = Worksheets("working").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 2))
```

and get the following Error:   "Application-defined or Object-defined error".

In the immediate Window, I am finding something very interesting.. assuming "r" has been dimmed and that the selected worksheet is (1) (not "working".. which is (2))

```
r = Worksheets("working").Range("A1:D2")   <<< THIS WORKS
r = Worksheets("working").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 2))   << ERROR
r = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 2)) <<< THIS WORKS (on selected sheet).
```

So I'm just confused and have been combing thru SO and other sites. I know I'm doing something obviously wrong... can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439376/what-is-the-default-scope-of-worksheets-and-cells-and-range/28439984#28439984

Comment: You need to qualify your `Cells` object

Comment: Thanks for the link... I'm happy urdearboy gave the example below since the "duplicate" did not give examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualify all objects (Including `Cells`).

```
Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("working")

Set r = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(4, 2))
```

Comment: Thank you!  But... that does not seem to work either.  r = ws.Range("A1:D2") where Set ws = Worksheets("working"), gives me the same error

Comment: Set workingRange = ws.Range("A1:B4") WORKS.

Comment: Set workingRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(0, 0), ws.Cells(4, rowNumber)) DOES NOT.

Comment: There's no `Cells(0, 0)` - row/column indexes begin at 1