# Excel VBA Sorting in Table Error 1004 "Method 'Range' of Object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with a table in excel and would like to sort the data in it by the 'Date Submitted'. However, I keep getting the error

> "Method 'Range' of Object '_Worksheet' failed.

I have tried numerous ways of accomplishing this but all return the same error.

The code is being written in a separate sheet from the sheet containing the table as that may be a source of the error.

Below is a brief overview of my most recent attempt to resolve this.

```
Sheets("Database").ListObjects("DatabaseTable").Sort.SortFields.Clear
Sheets("Database").ListObjects("DatabaseTable").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("DatabaseTable[Date Submitted]"), Order:=xlAscending
Sheets("Database").ListObjects("DatabaseTable").Sort.Apply
```

Comment: Is this in a sheet code module then?

Comment: No, the workbook contains three sheets. The code is in 'Sheet1' and the ListObject is in 'Sheet2'. Would best practice be to put this into its own module and call the routine instead?

Comment: If the code is in 'Sheet1', that's a sheet code module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With unqualified `Range` calls in a sheet code module, the implicit qualifier is `Me`, i.e. the sheet containing the code, or `Sheet1` - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439376/what-is-the-default-scope-of-worksheets-and-cells-and-range).

So

```
Range("DatabaseTable[Date Submitted]")
```

is equivalent to

```
Me.Range("DatabaseTable[Date Submitted]")
```

or

```
Sheet1.Range("DatabaseTable[Date Submitted]")
```

Since the table is on `Sheet2`, you need:

```
Sheet2.Range("DatabaseTable[Date Submitted]")
```

In summary (from the linked question):

> The easy way to avoid having to remember any of this is to *always fully qualify* any `Worksheets`, `Sheets`, `Range`, `Cells`, or `Names` reference.*

N.B. `Columns` and `Rows` need qualifying too.

Comment: Quoted list is missing `Columns` and `Rows` =)

Comment: YEP. Those tend to sneak by... I am going to add.