# Reading data from ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a code and have particular problem with reading data ranges from different sheets. The problematic partition of the code is:

```
Dim INP, TMP as worksheet
Set INP = Sheets("Input")
Set TMP = Sheets("Temp")
TMP.Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(1,3)).Value = INP.Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(1,3)).Value
```

Which, instead of writing the values from the range on input sheet to the range on Temp sheet, gives an

> error 1004 (Method range of worksheet failed).

Can you guys help me solve this?

Comment: Qualify your `Cells` references with `TMP.` or `INP.` as well. They are not implied. And Dim your `INP` as a worksheet too. The way you have it now, it is a variant.

Comment: Agree with @braX, reference to the range needs to be changed to `TMP.Range(TMP.Cells(1, 1), TMP.Cells(1, 3)).Value = INP.Range(INP.Cells(1, 1), INP.Cells(1, 3)).Value`, or like this `TMP.Range("A1:C1").Value = INP.Range("A1:C1").Value`

Comment: Thanks @braX, that helped. Both of the sheet variables are declared in one row, so that should be fine.  To Vasily, your second option is not possible, since i need to use variable rows and columns in the ranges, this was just a simplified case. Nevertheless, thanks to both of you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439376/what-is-the-default-scope-of-worksheets-and-cells-and-range/28439984#28439984

Comment: No, `Dim INP, TMP as worksheet` is not the same as `Dim INP as worksheet, TMP as worksheet`

Comment: Did not know that, thank's. Does not affect the code though..., but good to know.

Comment: Did you try as @VasilyIvoyzha suggested by not using `Cells` at all? And yes, you can still use variable rows.

Comment: Not only rows, but also columns. Your first suggestion was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
Dim INP As Worksheet, TMP As Worksheet

Set INP = Sheets("Input")
Set TMP = Sheets("Temp")
INP.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 3)).Copy Destination:=TMP.Cells(1, 1)
```

This code will paste values and formats.

Comment: Shouldn't be, but you can try `INP.Range("A1:C1").Copy Destination:=TMP.Cells(1,1)`

Comment: I don’t want to use copy method here. But thanks. It is already solved