# Transferring range of data to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

In sheet1 I have data.
I want to export data from B4 to AN4 (name of company) and from B20 to AN20 (average score).

Selecting data from only B4 and B20 gives the result I want.

I want to set a range from B4 to AN4 for company and B20 and AN20 for average.

```vb
Sub results()      
    
    Dim company As String, average As Integer
    Worksheets("sheet1").Select
    company = Range("B4:AN4")
    average = Range("B20:AN4")
    Worksheets("sheet2").Select
    Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A4").Select
    If Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A4").Offset(1, 0) <> “” Then
        Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A4").End(xlDown).Select
    End If
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = company
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = average
    Worksheets("sheet1").Select
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C4").Select
    
End Sub
```

Worksheet example:
[image: Worksheet example:]

Comment: Can you attach a sample workbook?

Comment: sure I edit the post and add screenshoot.

Comment: can you paste a picture of sheet 2 also? thanks

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a few things

1. When you scale from a single cell to multiple cells, you have not defined `company` and `average` as range but you are trying to set them to a range (you've declared as string and double respectively) so this line and the next will throw an error `company = Range("B4:AN4")`. If you have `option explicit` you will not permit these errors.
2. your average range is not correct. Should be `b20:an20` not `b20:an4`
3. your destination is not correct I think
4. you need to copy values so that you do not copy formulas for the average

Absent confirming sheet2 expected output, this is my best understanding of what you want

A general piece of advice, try to avoid using select and use fully qualified ranges ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439376/what-is-the-default-scope-of-worksheets-and-cells-and-range/28439984#28439984))

```
Option Explicit
Sub results()

Dim ws_in As Worksheet
Set ws_in = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws_out As Worksheet
Set ws_out = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim company As Range, average As Range
Set company = ws_in.Range("B4:AN4")
Set average = ws_in.Range("B20:AN20")

Dim r_out As Range
Set r_out = ws_out.Range("B4")

' ensure output is an empty cell catering for 0, 1, and > 1 row already existing
If Not IsEmpty(r_out.Value) Then
  If Not IsEmpty(r_out.Offset(1, 0).Value) Then
    Set r_out = r_out.End(xlDown)
  End If
  Set r_out = r_out.Offset(1, 0)
End If

company.Copy r_out
average.Copy
r_out.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and great advice about avoiding "select", this is great!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyRangesTo()
    'Set your ranges, sepatate by coma
    Range("B4:AN4,B20:AN20").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets ("yourDestinationSheetName")
    'range("A1").select ' range you will paste <--CHECK HERE
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```