# Excel VBA Formula for multiple inputs

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write an Excel VBA code that allows me to take values from 5 different cells and run it through a formula to produce a single number. I would like it to work as the prebuilt functions in excel work but can't get the inputs right. This is what I have so far.

```
Public Function compression(Limit, time, timeset, alpha, beta)
Sub compression(Limit, time, timeset, alpha, beta)
'Limiting Compression Strength = LCS
'Time = t
'Alpha =a
'Beta = b
'Setting Time = ts
'Compression Strength = f
Limit = LCS
time = t
timeset = ts
alpha = a
beta = b
x = -((t - ts) / a) ^ b
y = 1 - Exp(x)
f = y * LCS
Range("targetRange") = f
End Sub
End Function
```

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need the `Sub`, the code goes within the `Function` that you should end like this: `Public Function compression(params) As X` being X the type you are returning. Then at the end of the function `compression = f`. You should also declare the input type for all your parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few observations and pointers for a self-declared newbie

1. Always use `option explicit` - it will force you to declare all variables so you dont get any errors from wrong types/typos - [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement)
2. always declare the type of the variable
3. always include `byref`/`byval` in function signatures - [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/differences-between-passing-an-argument-by-value-and-by-reference)
4. your function needs to return a value
5. When you define a range or use any of[`Range`/`Cells`/`Sheets`/`Worksheets`/`Workbooks`], explicitly specify the parent - "[fully qualify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439376/what-is-the-default-scope-of-worksheets-and-cells-and-range)"
6. Try not to change ranges in a function - use subs to do that

[Happy coding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office)

Tweaking your code:

```
option explicit
' underscore is line continuation marker
Public Function compression(byref Limit as double, _
       byref time as double, _
       byref timeset as double, _
       byref alpha as double, _
       byref beta as double) as double
'Limiting Compression Strength = LCS
'Time = t
'Alpha =a
'Beta = b
'Setting Time = ts
'Compression Strength = f

'Limit = LCS
' this is an error, Limit, time, alpha, beta and timeest are passed in and 
' you are setting them to undeclared variables. 
' because you do not have option explcit you are able to use undeclared variables
' they will default to zero in this instance and so you are overwriting the passed values of
' Limit, time, alpha, beta and timeest to be zero with these statements
'time = t
'timeset = ts
'alpha = a
'beta = b
  dim x as double, y as double, f as double

  x = -((time - timeset) / alpha) ^ beta
  y = 1 - Exp(x)
  f = y * Limit
  ' this sets the return value
  compression = f
End Function
```

Comment: Last piece of advice - using the macro recorder is a great way to learn VBA and the object model