# Can I take implicitly take a worksheet argument in a with statement?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub that looks like this:

```
Public Sub CategoryChange(ChangeWS As Worksheet, NewCategory As String, StartDate As String, EndDate As String)
    ...
End Sub
```

And I'm wondering why this works:

```
Sub Test()

    Call CategoryChange(ActiveSheet, Range("A1"), Range("A2"), Range("A3"))

End Sub
```

and this doesn't work (compile error, argument not optional):

```
Sub Test2()

    With ActiveSheet

        Call CategoryChange(, Range("A1"), Range("A2"), Range("A3"))

    End With

End Sub
```

If my sub is expecting a worksheet variable and I'm writing within a `With` statement, why won't it implicitly take my worksheet?

Comment: You're misunderstanding how `With` works. Also note that without the `.` in front of each `Range` call, none of them are actually referring to `With ActiveSheet`.

Comment: @BigBen Clearly!

Comment: @BigBen I understand the missing periods in from the `Range`s, I'm just curious about the first argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that because the syntax doesn't work that way. [`With`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement) only provides a shortcut to reference *members* of an object, not the object itself. It doesn't "magically" inject the object into a missing reference to the variable. It only looks for expressions that start with a period (`.`) with no reference in front and injects the object reference.

If your example actually *compiles*, then `Range` must be referring to some other reference, not `ActiveSheet.Range`. Otherwise, you would do this:

```
With ActiveSheet

    Call CategoryChange(ActiveSheet, .Range("A1"), .Range("A2"), .Range("A3"))

End With
```

Comment: Seems like the italics were meant to be around "actually" and not "compiles", but otherwise, quite well said.

Comment: Slightly confusingly for this example, `Range()` without an explicit object qualifier always refers to a range on `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: @acuparia [not technically true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439376/what-is-the-default-scope-of-worksheets-and-cells-and-range) but yeah, here it just so happens that the implicit `ActiveSheet` (assuming OP's code is in a regular module) is the same as the explicit `With ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Thanks - see, I think I thought it looked silly to have to write `ActiveSheet` inside of my with statement.

Answer (score 0):

`With` just lets you access the properties and methods of an object without having to specify the object each time:

```
Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Select
```

Is the same as:

```
With Worksheets(1)
  .Range("A1").Select
End With
```

the period is needed; missing arguments are still treated as missing arguments.  In your example, this should work:

```
With ActiveSheet

        Call CategoryChange(Worksheets(.Name), Range("A1"), Range("A2"), Range("A3"))

End With
```

as `.Name` will return the name of the object referenced by the `With` block.  But it hardly seems worth the effort!