# Copy worksheets that contain more than X rows of data to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, worksheet

I have 100 worksheets within one workbook (A). I would like to copy worksheets that contain more than 35 rows of data into workbook (B).

The code I wrote copies worksheets that have less than 35 rows of data.

```vb
Sub Split_workbook()

Dim last_row as long  
Dim sh as worksheet   
For Each sh In Worksheets   
    last_row = cells(rows.count,"A").End(xlUp).Row    
    If last_row >= 35 Then   
        sh.Copy after:=workbooks("B.xlsx").Sheets(Workbooks("B.xlsx").Sheets.count)   
    End if   
    Workbooks("A.xlsx").activate  
Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: `last_row = sh.cells(sh.rows.count,"A").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439376/what-is-the-default-scope-of-worksheets-and-cells-and-range/28439984#28439984

Comment: Thank you BigBen. That works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Copy Worksheets

- Running the code from one workbook (`ThisWorkbook`), copies certain worksheets from another open workbook (`A.xlsx`) to yet another (a third) open workbook (`B.xlsx`).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub splitWorkbook()
    
    Const ProcName As String = "splitWorkbook"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    Const srLimit As Long = 35
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks("A.xlsx")
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = swb.Worksheets(1).Rows.Count
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks("B.xlsx")
     
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim sLastRow As Long
    Dim dCount As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
        sLastRow = sws.Cells(srCount, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If sLastRow >= srLimit Then
            dCount = dCount + 1
            sws.Copy After:=dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count)
        End If
    Next sws
    'swb.Close False
    'dwb.Close True
    
ProcExit:
    
    If Not Application.ScreenUpdating Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
    
    Select Case dCount
    Case 0
        MsgBox "No worksheets copied.", vbExclamation, "Fail?"
    Case 1
        MsgBox "Copied 1 worksheet.", vbInformation, "Success"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Copied " & dCount & " worksheets.", vbInformation, "Success"
    End Select
    
    Exit Sub

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any reason that we introduce their workbook instead of just playing with two workbooks?

Comment: A `.xlsx` file can't have code, so I assumed there is a third file (`.xlsm` or `.xlsb`). I can rewrite it easily for two files if you explain which of them should contain the code: `A.xlsm` or `B.xlsm` (or `.xlsb`)? For example, if the code is in `dwb`, then replace `Set dwb = Workbooks("B.xlsx")` with `Set dwb = ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: I see, thank you for explaining. Actually A file is xlsm, I have a typo above. thought I wrote A.xlsm.