# VBA Excel ComboBox value to Range ("specific cell" to last column with data)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fill a range of cells from a single ComboBox and I am not sure why my modified code of declaring range from cell down to last used row doesn't work when I flip it horizontally and declare range from cell to last used column on the right of the specified cell which is "C1"

```
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    LastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Worksheets("Machine Format").Range("C2" & LastColumn).Value = UserForm_Home.Language_ComboBox.Text
```

I am judging if it's the last used column by it's header row which won't be blank.

Could someone, please, help me with this code?

Comment: Hmm, it fills range "C2:C5" for some reason

Comment: Do you want filling of all the range `"C2:C" & lastRow`? Or to place the combo value in the last cell of C:C column. For the first case, please follow BigBen suggestion, for the second case, please use `Range("C" & LastRow).Value`. If you want to place it on the first empty cell, you should use `Range("C" & LastRow + 1).Value`. For the last empty column `.Range("C2", .Cells(2, LastColumn + 1))`...

Comment: Sorry, `.Range("C2", .Cells(2, LastColumn))`.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you, mate! Your code has a mistake, but it still helped me!
Code should be .Range("C2", Cells(2, LastColumn))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with the column index, use `Cells` instead of `Range`.

```
With Worksheets("Machine Format")
    .Range("C2", .Cells(2, LastColumn)).Value = UserForm_Home.Language_ComboBox.Text
End WIth
```

Use `With Worksheets("Machine Format")` and a period `.` before `Cells` to properly qualify the worksheet for the `Cells` call.

Comment: Thank you, mate! Your code has a mistake, but it still helped me! Code should be .Range("C2", Cells(2, LastColumn))

Comment: @Eduards - use `With`, and yes include the `.` before `Cells`.

Comment: No need for with. It works like intended :)

Comment: No it doesn't.... it'll fail when the `MachineFormat` sheet is not active. `Cells` *needs* to be qualified with the worksheet, otherwise it's implicitly the `ActiveSheet`, or `Me` if this code is in a sheet code module.

Comment: [More reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28439984/9245853).