# Why is this giving me an error? Range(Cells,Cells) selection

Tags: excel, vba

I seem to be getting an error on this, and I do not understand why, I know I can just use Range with letters but I want to learn how to do it in this format.

```
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("t").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2)).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2)).Value
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Amit Application-Defined or object-defined error I am using Excel 2013, it is really strange because if I replace it with 1 cell with works or if I just use an alphanumeric range it works.

Comment: When you use Cells(1, 1) you're implicitly using ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).  You have to qualify it.

Comment: @Sobigen what would be the shortest way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: As Sobigen said, you have to qualify the Cells() methods you're calling in the Range() method.  See this post for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962890/2-ways-for-clearcontents-on-vba-excel-but-1-work-fine-why/18962945#18962945

Answer (score 2):

Here's my test code, I added some worksheet objects to make it a read a little easier.  You have to qualify the `Range` too if working from a worksheet module, if you're in a plain module you can leave it out.

```
sub test()
    dim t as worksheet
    dim one as worksheet

    set t = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("t")
    set one = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1")

    t.Range(t.Cells(1, 1), t.Cells(2, 2)).Value = one.Range(one.Cells(1, 1), one.Cells(2, 2)).Value

    'Alternatively, what Jeeped is referencing in his comment:
    with ThisWorkbook.Sheets("t")
        .range(.cells(1, 1), .cells(2, 2).value = one.Range(one.cells(1, 1), one .Cells(2,2)).value
    end with
end sub
```

Comment: A [With...End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) could elimiate at least one of the worksheet references.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Sobigen gives a good way to qualify your references to avoid the error.

You can also avoid `Cells` altogether by using `Resize`.

```
Sub UseResizeInsteadOfCells()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("t").Range("A1").Resize(2, 2).Value = _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("A1").Resize(2, 2).Value

End Sub
```

I used `A1` since you are doing `Cells(1,1)` on a `Worksheet` which is the same reference.  You could also use `.Cells(1,1).Resize(2,2)` and get the same result without worrying about qualifying references inside a `Range` call.