# Avoiding Select in VBA Excel macros with variable ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I was following suggestions under question [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros), but still getting  "Application-defined or object-defined error".

My macro suppose to check value in one of lines, compare it with set value, and if values equals, then copy line to another sheet. I tried to avoid usage of .Select command, but no matter what I try I'm getting errors.

This is my last version:

```
    Counter2 = 17
    For Counter1 = 12 To 150

    Dim S As Worksheet
    Dim R As Worksheet
    Dim SL As Range
    Dim RL As Range
    Set R = Sheets("Front")
    Set S = Sheets("CHECK LIST")
    Set SL = S.Range(Cells(Counter1, 1), Cells(Counter1, 10))
    Set RL = R.Range(Cells(Counter2, 1), Cells(Counter2, 10))

    Set curCell = Worksheets("CHECK LIST").Cells(Counter1, 6)
    Set checkCell = Worksheets("Front").Cells(3, 5)
        If curCell.Value = checkCell.Value Then

            With S
                .SL.Copy
            End With

            With R
                .RL.PasteSpecial
            End With

            Counter2 = Counter2 + 1

        End If
Next Counter1
```

Is this something to do with usage of variables (Counter1, Counter2) in Range?

Comment: What line has the error?

Comment: I don't think those with statements are necessary.  Neither the dot infront of `SL` and `RL`

Comment: This has been answered before many times: qualify both Range and Cells with the worksheet: `S.Range(S.Cells(Counter1, 1), S.Cells(Counter1, 10))` and so on

Comment: @Rory's got it -- when you're using ranges, it's best (if not required) to qualify each part of that range.  Otherwise, while the Range might be "S.Range" reference, the Cells() part of that might refer to the activesheet, or some other sheet.  Best to be explicit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [2 ways for "ClearContents" on VBA Excel, but 1 work fine. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962890/2-ways-for-clearcontents-on-vba-excel-but-1-work-fine-why)

Comment: @Byron. No, not a duplicate.

Comment: @ChipsLetten, this question has multiple sets of errors.  It's definitely a duplicate w/ the unqualified reference to `Cells`.  After that, the code won't run with the improper usage of `With S` and `.SL` and `.RL` which don't exist under that object.  This is also pointed out by chancea in the second comment.  I suspect misusing a variable like that is a duplicate somewhere.  I'll see if I can find one.  Regardless, this isn't a great question because the issue on `With` is a `Compile error` and OP is reporting a runtime `Application error` which would come from `Range`.

Answer (score 1):

The errors are probably being caused by the `Copy` and `PasteSpecial` lines in this block of code:

> ```
>         With S
>             .SL.Copy
>         End With  
>         With R
>             .RL.PasteSpecial
>         End With
> ```

Once you have `Set` a range variable, Excel knows which worksheet and which workbook contains that range variable. If you want to do something to the range then you do not need to include the worksheet. So, in your code, you just use

```
SL.Copy
RL. PasteSpecial
```

It is always a good idea to think if you have any code inside a loop that should be outside. In your code you `Set` your worksheet variables within the loop but this should be done once before the loop. Adding in the comments made to your post, your code should be changed to:

```
Dim S As Worksheet
Dim R As Worksheet
Set R = Sheets("Front")
Set S = Sheets("CHECK LIST")

Counter2 = 17
For Counter1 = 12 To 150

    Dim SL As Range
    Dim RL As Range
    Set SL = S.Range(S.Cells(Counter1, 1), S.Cells(Counter1, 10))
    Set RL = R.Range(R.Cells(Counter2, 1), R.Cells(Counter2, 10))

    Set curCell = Worksheets("CHECK LIST").Cells(Counter1, 6)
    Set checkCell = Worksheets("Front").Cells(3, 5)
    If curCell.Value = checkCell.Value Then

        SL.Copy
        RL.PasteSpecial

        Counter2 = Counter2 + 1
    End If
Next Counter1
```

The `PasteSpecial` method has several parameters:

```
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, _
            Transpose:=False
```

If you are not using these, then maybe you can do a "normal" copy & paste?

```
SL.Copy RL
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this is not about Excel "knowing" which `Worksheet` contains the `Range`.  The problem is that a `Worksheet` like `S` or `R` does not contain an object called `SL` or `RL`.  Even if `SL` and `RL` were not defined variables, this code would still error because Excel knows those objects don't exist for a `Worksheet`.  It throws the compile time error since it knows before running that this is not valid code.

Comment: I agree with your other changes and the good practice of using `Set` outside the loop to avoid resetting those variables constantly when they don't change.  It's also possible to pull `RL` out of the `Counter1` loop.  The simplified usage of `Copy` is also a good idea.