# Application defined or object oriented error. Code working from sheet and not working from another

Tags: excel, vba

```
irow1 = Sheets("Customer Template").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Row
Sheets("Customer Template").Cells(irow1 + 1, 11) = "Total"
Sheets("Customer Template").Cells(irow1 + 1, 12) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("Customer Template").Range(Cells(6, 12), Cells(irow1, 12)))
Sheets("Customer Template").Cells(irow1 + 1, 13) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("Customer Template").Range(Cells(6, 13), Cells(irow1, 13)))
```

This code while running in Customer Template Sheet its working properly, but when running from different sheet its throwing an error as application defined error. Debug error is showing in last two rows.
Please anyone help on this.

Comment: Add `Sheets("Customer Template").` before `Cells(irow1, 12)` and `Cells(irow1, 13)` as well ;)

Comment: Such questions have been answered so many times in the past...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962890/2-ways-for-clearcontents-on-vba-excel-but-1-work-fine-why

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368220/is-the-in-range-necessary-when-defined-by-cells