# Range fails if sheet is not selected

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code which should work fine

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Auswertung")
...
ws.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).NumberFormat = "0"
```

It however fails if the sheet is not selected. Error 1004, Methode Range fails for the object.

If I change it to

```
ws.Select
ws.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).NumberFormat = "0"
```

it works.

why? In VBA I want to avoid `select`.

Comment: you need to qualify `Cells` too... `ws.Cells`

Comment: @braX why do you not need to qualify it when using select?

Comment: @theVBE-it'srightforme Cause otherwise`Cells`refers implicit to ActiveSheet, what may be the wrong sheet.

Comment: Unqualified Cells / Range objects always point to the ActiveSheet. When "Auswetung" is selected, Cells points to it. If another sheet is selected, it points to that one.

The reason you're getting an error is because you're trying to create a range on ws (`ws.Range`) using cells that are on another sheet (`[ActiveSheet.]Cells(2,2)`)

Comment: use:    `With ws
        .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).NumberFormat = "0"
    End with`

Comment: @ComputerVersteher that would have been my guess!

Comment: This has been answered more than 10 times and should be closed as a duplicate :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439376/what-is-the-default-scope-of-worksheets-and-cells-and-range

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962890/2-ways-for-clearcontents-on-vba-excel-but-1-work-fine-why

Answer (score 5):

you need to qualify `Cells` too... The `Cells` reference does not automatically assume it's referencing the same sheet as your `ws.Range` like you are expecting. It's using the assumed `ActiveSheet` unlike your `Range` object.

**Option 1:**

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 2), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).NumberFormat = "0"
```

**Option 2:**

```
With ws
  .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).NumberFormat = "0"
End With
```