# Application.Match only working on Lookup tab active

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm using Userforms and have 2 main worksheets. 1 (shE) collates the information selected, and 2 (shL) is where all available options are stored - these are my lookups.

shL has a list of teams on Row 2, every 4 columns, and on Row 3, a list of attributes for each team. So the structure is AB2 = Team1, AF2 = Team2, AJ2 = Team3. AB3 = Attribute1, AC3 = Attribute2, AD3 = Attribute3, AE3 = Attribute4, AF3 = Attribute1 etc..

```
Dim shE, shL as Worksheet
Dim FoundTeam as range
Dim c, cc, y, mtc as long
    Set shE = Sheets("EnteredData")
    Set shL = Sheets("Lookups")
    Set FoundTeam = shL.Range("AB2:BX2").Find(what:=shE.Range("D10"))
    c = FoundTeam.Column
    cc = c + 3
    y = shL.Cells(shL.Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
    ' the next line of code causes the run-time error 1004 if shL is not the last-active worksheet
    mtc = Application.Match(shE.Range("J3"), shL.Range(Cells(4, cc), Cells(y, cc)), 0)
        shE.Range("Q3").Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(shL.Range(Cells(4, c), Cells(y, c)), mtc) 'this is actually part of a loop so the shE.Range("Q3") is more like ("Q" & i)
```

For clarity, `shE.Range("J3")` stores the Attribute4 (selectable by the user) (found in shL 4th column of each Team) and `shE.Range("D10")` is the Team Name.

The issue I'm having is that the code works perfectly **if shL is the last-active worksheet on Excel.** However, if the last-active worksheet is shE (or any other worksheet), I will get the *Run-time error 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed*.

I don't understand why this code only works if shL is last-active. This will be used by several different people in my organization and they will not have shL visible to them.

What can I do to fix the run-time error, or is there a way to lookup/find/pull the information better?

Comment: Try fully qualifying all the ranges. For example Cells(... should be SheetCodeName.Cells(...

Comment: In `VBA` you have to declare all your variables individually. so your `Dim c, cc, y, mtc as long` translates to: `mtc = Long` and all other variables in this line are of type `Variant`. Change this to: `Dim c As Long, cc As Long, y As Long, mtc as long`

Comment: @RicardoDiaz - I think my cells are already fully qualified. The sheet is identified by the shL which has been specified in the Dim. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Zac - thanks for the feedback. I had a nagging suspicion about that, but glad of the confirmation. I have now amended all of my variables. It hasn't made a blind bit of difference to the functionality of this code, but at least my variables are properly referenced. Thanks

Comment: @Marc just to clarify, this is not fully qualified: `shL.Range(Cells(4, cc), Cells(y, cc))` see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18962945/1521579)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the workaround I found. Not ideal, but it seems to work.
In every attempt I made (`Match` and `Find` were both exhausted), the code worked great if I was on `shL` but not if I was elsewhere; the `Match` just wouldn't work consistently. So I decided against doing it in VBA!

```
'Variables
Dim shE As Worksheet, shL As Worksheet
Dim ClmnLtrc As String, ClmnLtrcc As String
Dim c As Long, cc As Long, y As Long, Q As Long
Dim FoundTeam As Range, FoundRange As Range

'Define variables
Set shE = Sheets("EnteredData")
Set shL = Sheets("Lookups")
Set FoundTeam = shL.Range("AB2:BX2").Find(what:=shE.Range("D10"))
    c = FoundTeam.Column
    cc = c + 3
    y = shL.Cells(shL.Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
    Q = shE.Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ClmnLtrc = Split(Cells(1, c).Address, "$")(1)
    ClmnLtrcc = Split(Cells(1, cc).Address, "$")(1)

'Write the Index Match into the cell
shE.Range("Q3").Value = "=INDEX(Lookups!$" & ClmnLtrc & "4:$" & ClmnLtrc & y & ",MATCH(EnteredData!$P$" & i & ",Lookups!$" & ClmnLtrcc & "$4:$" & ClmnLtrcc & y & ",0))"

'Convert the result to text
    shE.Range("Q3:Q" & Q).Copy
    shE.Range("Q3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

I hope this can help someone else one day. Just because we write in VBA, doesn't mean everything has to be in VBA.